# When profiling a Mongo query, what does "millis" mean?

Tags: java, mongodb, streaming, profiling

We are working on an application where Java code talks to Mongo and streams the results back with Spring Data. We have been looking at the profiler output and I am not 100% on what it means.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/

```
{
  "op" : "query",
   "ns" : "test.c",
   "query" : {
      "find" : "c",
      "filter" : {
         "a" : 1
      }
   },
   "keysExamined" : 2,
   "docsExamined" : 2,
   "cursorExhausted" : true,
 ...
 "responseLength" : 108,
 "millis" : 0,
```

The documentation's description is:

> system.profile.millis
>   The time in milliseconds from the perspective of the mongod from the beginning of the operation to the end of the operation.

OK, but what is the operation? If I am executing a query and I am pulling 1000 results back, is the "millis" time just for the query plan? Or does it include the ENTIRE it spends pulling the results back and sending them to the driver?

Will this give different answers when streaming vs non-streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation is the query; the query does not return documents, but instead returns a cursor that points to the locations of the documents on disk:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/cursors/

The "millis" result is the time it takes MongoDB to search for the query results (perform index or collection scan, identify all documents that meet the query criteria and perform sorts if necessary) and return the corresponding cursor to the driver.

I'm not certain with what you mean by "streaming", but it could be the driver iterating over the cursor to access the results of the query.